# Octane-Jenkins execution node

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, hp-uft

I am trying to run UFT tests from octane to jenkins and it generates a job which shows that execution node.

It is possible to modify that parameter somewhere, because it stays in the queue
[image]

Comment: it was solved by adding said label in the node, you're welcome